# How do I run an animation for a short period of time?

Tags: android

I have a looping animation I want to present for an image button before a static image is used; on each button press.  Is there a way to run this animation for around 2000 milliseconds then switch over to the image.  What I have tried just results in a pause then the static image.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){         

      @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

       animationrun();
             long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
             time += 2000;
             while(time > System.currentTimeMillis())
             {}

       select();        


   }

     });

     public void animationrun()
 {
 button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_anim);
        animation = (AnimationDrawable)button.getBackground();
        animation.start();
 }



      public void select()
     { 
     button.setBackgroundResource(R.solidImage); 
     }
```

SOLUTION: http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=128857303793437&topic=74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `Animation` [duration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setDuration(long)), and using an [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html), `onAnimationEnd()`

Comment: Because its a drawable I cant do this... but: http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=128857303793437&topic=74 this does work